# What part omits the hash fragment from the url or why crawlers do not simply send the fragment?

Tags: http, fragment

I was asked a simple question the other day and I was amazed I do not know the answer nor can I find it online easily.

I know fragments in the URL do not reach the backend. but I am unclear about who is stripping that part from the URL before it reaches the backend.

I want my question to be very clear as I am looking for a very clear answer:

[In wikipedia they say](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)
`Clients are not supposed to send URI-fragments to servers when they retrieve a document`

From this I understand that browsers remove the fragment, that `curl` removes that fragment and that `wget` etc..

on the other hand, there's this whole SEO issue with crawlers where they identify the `#!` combination and then they transform it to `_escaped_fragment_` - **but this is what I don't get** - why don't the crawlers simply send the fragment?? why go to all that trouble? wouldn't life be easier if some clients DID send the fragment?

I can only assume that the servers (nginx, apache http, application server like node http, rails etc..) strip the fragment, but I don't understand the motivation behind it, why should they?

can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know fragments in the URL do not reach the backend. but I am unclear about who is stripping that part from the URL before it reaches the backend.

Obviously, this is exactly what the [HTTP 1.1 Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) states...everyone (browser vendors) "should" adhere to the specifications. The main reason behind it is the security implications of disclosing user's personal information. You can go through the specs and I'm pretty sure it'll become clearer to you. For example, in [closure 5.5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2) you can see this statement related to the referer header...

> A user agent MUST NOT include the fragment and userinfo components of the
> URI reference [RFC3986], if any, when generating the Referer field
> value.

another example is in [closure 9.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-9.5) related to redirects...

> this might have the effect of
> disclosing one site's fragment to another site.  If the first site
> uses personal information in fragments, it ought to ensure that
> redirects to other sites include a (possibly empty) fragment
> component in order to block that inheritance

The security implications are quite clear, but if you still don't understand the security implications at least you should trust it and follow the specifications...that's what browser vendors do (well, sometimes), they follow the specifications

Your second question related to ajax requests, crawlers and fragments is still related to the above-mentioned specifications. The specifications state that clients MUST NOT send fragments to the server. What's a crawler? A client requesting data, so the same applies. So, to this question/statement of yours...

> wouldn't life be easier if some clients DID send the fragment?

The answer (based on the above) is NO, life would be easier if there weren't security issues and people with bad intentions.

Crawlers might need to crawl ajax pages that uses fragment. In order to be able to request that content from the server (that supposedly don't understand fragments) they use a query string variable (`_escaped_fragment_`), however, your server needs to know what to do with that query string, in order words, you need to implement it, you need to respond to that request as if it were an ajax request coming from a user's browser. You can read more about it in the [Google Webmaster Docs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)

If you are still having problems to understand it, just ask what's still not clear. But be nice ;)...I didn't write the http 1.1 specifications and not the absolute expert.